# How can I enable Ctrl+Alt+Backspace?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> can usually be set to restart X, however I can't find the option to allow this (it is disabled by default).

I have looked in `System->Preferences->Keyboard` and `System->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts` but I can't find an option to enable it.

Where can I change this setting?

Comment: How can I do it in 14.04? I can't see a Layouts tab.

Comment: **TL;DR**: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### For Unity (13.04 to 17.04):

You want: System->Preferences->Keyboard

Then click the Layouts tab, the Options button, and expand *Key sequence to kill the X server*, before finally selecting the checkbox.

[image: Screenshot]

To enable it via the command line install [dontzap](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dontzap) [image: Install dontzap]

```
sudo apt-get install dontzap
```

And in a terminal

```
sudo dontzap --enable
```

To disable  the shortcut:

```
sudo dontzap --disable
```

Comment: The `dontzap` package is not included in Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: For me, it *appears to be* disabled in `System->Preferences->Keyboard` but in fact it's still active, destructive and "out there". `dontzap` doesn't seem to be "active" (as in actively developed) either, and it seems counterintuitive to have to install it in order to disable this key-combo. Any other ways to *really and fully* disable it?

Comment: ps: I think this is a **bug**. Some time ago, I *enabled* it cuz I thought it was *kinda cool* - not knowing that it was a one-way-street (no disabling functionality built-in). pps: I'm on `precise`.

Comment: The `System->Preferences->Keyboard` works also for Ubuntu 14.04 with MATE desktop.

Comment: Where exactly is the option to enable this shortcut on 16.04? [Cannot find it](https://i.imgur.com/MwTTmzd.png).

Answer (score 68):

This was tested on 13.10+, type the following on the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

[image]

You will see the **keyboard configuration**. Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> 5 times to skip all keyboard related options except for the Kill X part. When you get to the Kill X option which looks like this:

[image]

Select **YES** and press enter. Wait a bit while everything configures and after that you should have the ability to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>BCKSPC</kbd> right on the current session. After saving any work you have pending, try it yourself.

Perfect to solve any visual issues or annoying apps.

Thank you @david-c it also looks like this works:

Sudo Edit the `/etc/default/keyboard` file and add the line `XKBPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"` to it, so it looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: This is probably the only solution here (short of using the control panel, I mean) that maintain the setting across keyboard layout switch.

Comment: this solution deserves upvote!

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: For some reason I had to reboot to make this take effect with KDM on Kubuntu 14.04 (despite I tried doing `sudo stop kdm; sudo start kdm` until I rebooted). After reboot it does work as expected.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Internally, it appears that this works by adding `XKBPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"` to `/etc/default/keyboard`

Comment: @DavidC.Thank you buddy. Updated answer. I like your method better.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado are you sure that correct attr name should be XKBOPTIONS instead of XKBPTIONS, on xubuntu 20 it looks as XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"

Comment: They might have changed it at some point. Do note that the answer was in 2014.

Answer (score 22):

You can also use `dconf-editor`. This option will make the setting persistent across sessions.

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

After starting the `dconf-editor`, navigate to *org >> gnome >> desktop >> input-sources*

Add the options that you need in `xkb-options`. The option strings are surrounded by single quotes and separated by commas. Be careful not to delete the brackets on the ends.

To enable <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> to kill the X-session, add `'terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp'`

You can use this method to enter most of the traditional xkb options that are no longer available in *System Settings >> Text Entry*. The exceptions are the settings for switching the keyboard layouts, which currently do not work because of a bug.

For a list of the options and the syntax, use `man 7 xkeyboard-config` in a terminal.

To run the commands equivalent to using `dconf-editor` from a terminal, you use

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp']"
```

Note the single quotes around the value, the square brackets around that, the double quotes around the whole thing. In other words, just like in `dconf-editor`.

Note that this will *delete your other settings* in xkb-options, if you have any.

You can get the existing settings with

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

If you don't change these values very often, it might be simplest to combine existing settings with the new one by hand and the run `gsettings set`.

It can also be done all at once on the command line. I've put it in a short script here to make it easier to read.

```
#!/bin/bash
options=$(echo $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options)|sed 's/]//g')", 'terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "$options"
```

The 2nd line gets the current values and concatenates the `terminate...` option. The sed command strips the right square bracket from the current values.

Note that while the argument string to the `gsettings get` command in the terminal needs double quotes around the value

```
"['val', 'val2']"
```

the argument string when run in a script should *not* have the double quotes.

```
['val', 'val2']
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is there a way to issue this as a command on a command-line?

Comment: It's not the same thing. The solution by Lasiewski only works one time, until reboot. He doesn't know a way tho make it permanent.

Comment: It doesn't work. `source ~/.profile` makes it work, but logout/login resets it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12167/discussion-between-nickolai-leschov-and-chaskes)

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov I added a new command line solution

Answer (score 20):

### For 13.10 and newer:

If you are looking for a solution which is independent of Gnome/KDE/Fluxbox or any Desktop Environment or Window Manager, try the following X Window System command. I need this because my Unity desktop is not loading (but X works fine), therefore there is no logout button.

From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/DontZap#Using_the_command_line

> Using the command line
>
> You can type the following command to enable Zapping immediately.
>
> `setxkbmap -option terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp`
>
> If you're happy with the new
>   behaviour you can add that command to your `~/.xinitrc` in order to make
>   the change permanent.

Also, according to the [Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseNotes#Ctrl-Alt-Backspace_disabled_by_default_in_Xorg.2C_configured_via_XKB), this has replaced the old `DontZap` feature from older versions of the X Window System.

> In addition, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> option is now configured as an X
>   keymap (XKB) option, replacing the X server "DontZap" option and
>   allowing per-user configuration of this setting.

This is explained further in the [Xorg X11R7.5 Release Notes](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/RELNOTES.txt) which, among other details, say:

> Users who wish to have this functionality available by default may
>   enable it via the XKB configuration option “terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp”.

Comment: @Jorge Castro @Stefan Lasiewski
Thanks for your advice. One-time option with setxkbmap works, but adding it to `~/.xinitrc` on 13.10 doesn't do anything. Probably, `~/.xinitrc` isn't used anymore on the latest Ubuntu? How do I enable Zapping permanently, then?

Comment: @Nickolai Leschov. I had the same problem. In 13.10, try the method using the dconf-editor described in the answer by chaskes.

Answer (score 8):

It was changed to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Prt Scr</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.

I can't remember exactly when it was but it was supposed to stop accidental usage.

The idea being those who know they need it will be able to find the new key combination easily enough.

And I think someone at the time suggested it would be easier to remember as it is alternative screen kill. I am not sure that is the case.

The functionality is still there but under a different key combination.

Comment: Just to mention "Alt + Prt Scr" is marked on most keyboards as "SysRq" (System request) to help you easily remember this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As it happens, this doesn't work on my laptop. Both `prt sc` and `sys rq` need `fn` to be pressed and cause gnome-screenshot to open; many times if I hold it down for too long.

Comment: -1. Alt + PrtScr + k or (SysRq + k) is a magic SysRq key combination that kills all processes on the current virtual console. It can be used to kill the X server, however it isn't the replacement for Ctrl + Alt + Bksp. In Ubuntu 9.04 Ctrl + Alt + Bksp got disabled (not removed) by default and could be enabled by setting a X server flag ('DontZap'), and as of Ubuntu 9.10 it's like described by fluteflute.

Comment: Found the release notes. The Ubuntu answer to this question is on this page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseNotes about half way down.

Answer (score 8):

(This is for Gnome Ubuntu, but I suppose it is the same for Unity --- please someone confirm this).

You should install `gnome-tweak-tool` (if not installed already) and run it. You will find the option you are looking for under "Typing":

[image: g-t-t typing]

If you feel more confortable with `dconf-editor` (or you do not want to install `gnome-tweak-tool`), you can open `dconf-editor`, navigate to `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources`, and then add the word "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp" to the `xkb-options`  property.

[image: dconf-editor xkb properties]

Note that the other properties in the list will be probably different for your keyboard.

Comment: Thank you....Gnome Tweak *does* work in Unity, however, it is very hard to see as the white background that should be behind the right box with the list and menu options is transparent so it shows whatever is behind it(setting a white background would be a workaround but it is still usable....)  The Dconf editor works as well and might be the better choice for readability but is a bit harder to use.....

Answer (score 2):

You can still get back <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> shortcut to restart X by opening a terminal and copy paste the following:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Comment: This answer was already given by Luis Alvarado above, including more detailed instructions.

Answer (score 2):

For **Ubuntu 20.04** with Gnome 3 desktop, with the **Gnome Tweaks app**:

1. Open Gnome Tweaks
2. Navigate to *Keyboard & Mouse* tab
3. Find and click the button: *Additional layout options*
4. In the list popping up, locate and expand the item labelled *Key sequence to kill the X server*
5. Check the checkbox for the desired key combination

   - probably it's gonna be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt+</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

***This didn't appear to change anything at all and didn't activate the key combination***.

In Kubuntu (KDE, plasma-framework version 5.23 on Kubuntu 16.04 Xenial) I found the option under **K > System Settings > Input Devices > Keyboard > Advanced**. Open the menu item "key sequence to kill X server" and check the only option "Ctrl + Alt + Backspace", apply.

Using `strace` I can see that this adds a line to /home/$USER/.config/kxkbrc which reads: `Options=terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp`.

The `setxkbmap` rule did work though and places a line reading `terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp = +terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)` in the /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev file.