# ctrl + alt + backspace does not work

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I enable Ctrl+Alt+Backspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10622/how-can-i-enable-ctrlaltbackspace)

My <kbd>Esc</kbd> key sequences (such as those used to restart x etc) don’t seem to work. For example when i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> which is supposed to restart x-server, nothing happens. Do I need to enable these separately?

Comment: If you are looking for an answer related with Ctrl+alt+backspace, so change you Ask title - sounds vague and hard to answer. Thanks!

Comment: definitely a duplicate - i should learn to use the search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this just for your user. *System -> Preferences -> Keyboard* go to the `Layouts` tab and select `Options`. Then check **Key sequence to kill X server**.

[image]

Or run `gnome-control-center` from a terminal if you're using a shell without that same menu hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

The killing key sequence can be enabled for all users by adding these lines to your xorg.conf configuration file:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "DontZap" "false"
EndSection
```