# How do I enable the ctrl+alt+backspace shortcut in 11.10 (gui)?

Tags: xorg, 11.10, lightdm

I know there is a command line solution here: [How can I enable Ctrl+Alt+Backspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10622/how-can-i-enable-ctrlaltbackspace)

However, I am looking to enable it the way you used to on previous versions (the settings are not there in GNOME 3.2 it seems).

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Comment: @JorgeCastro: aww... I was hoping I was missing something :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well... I feel a wee bit stupid.

The latest GNOME Control Centre update brought the option back:
[image: bam!]

[image: bam!!]

[image: bam!!!]