# Dual monitor problem on disconnect

Tags: 11.04, multiple-monitors, external-monitor

I'm using a dual monitor setup on a Samsung QX412 laptop. My external monitor is connected via HDMI. I am NOT using the additional Nvidia drivers.Ubuntu uses Gnome 2 when I install them, so they don't seem to work for my configuration.

Dual monitors work fine, but trouble arises when I unplug the HDMI cable:

On first unplug nothing happens - the external montor goes black of course, but I still can go through the edge of the screen. When I reconnect and disconnect a second time, things work as expected most of the time - windows being resized and transferred to my laptops display.

On something like every third disconnect of the external monitor, the laptop screen will just go black, or display orange stripes. In very few cases the display can be restored by switching between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. Having the "Monitor Preferences" dialog open will sometimes help to restore a broken display. Reconnecting the external monitor is the same pain.

Does anyone have any idea how I could get this to work? I'd even be okay with a shortcut that tells my display manager, "Hey, you're broken - restart yourself". But the old <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> shortcut doesn't work any more.

Comment: Over at Unix, there's a similar question:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7622/edid-information, maybe of some help.

Comment: Hmmm :( Sorry, did not help. I even have a hard time to understand how this relates to my problem, but thanks for giving a hint anyway!

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem with HP 6460b (core i5) and htp 6710b (core duo) laptops... I'm used to unplug my laptop very often during the day (walking from one meeting to another, connecting to projector, etc).

Comment: About the restarting X server shortcut key, take a look at [How can I enable Ctrl+Alt+Backspace?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10622/how-can-i-enable-ctrlaltbackspace). Other than that, this questions looks to be abandoned. Voting to close it off as such

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)