# What to do when ubuntu 16.04 LTS stops responding

Tags: freeze, responsiveness

I have upgraded from ubuntu 15.04 to 16.04 LTS last week and since then it frequently stops responding completely and I have to use the power button to shut it down . Please tell what to do so that the problem can be solved without shutting it down ( as I lose that session and all my work is dicarded without being saved ) .

Comment: uuuuh what you did actually... I think. Other options are for techie people I bet this would also happen in System76, Entroware and other pre-installed laptops.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use virtual console by command:

```
ctrl + alt + F1
```

here you can check your processes by `top` command.

Exit from console: `ctrl + alt + F8`

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered a similar problem a while ago. The problem was with the default video driver and it was solved when I changed it 
(in my case, I changed the default one to 'fglrx-updates (proprietary)' driver for my AMD graphic card).
I am also a newbie to Ubuntu. So I am not sure it is the same problem with you. However you can try changing the video driver from

> System Settings > Software Sources > Additional Drivers

Comment: I also found that Mate was using the Noveua or wtv driver when my card used Skylake in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to a virtual console and then killing LightDm and restarting it does the trick without having to reboot the whole computer

```
ctrl + alt + F1 - F7
ps xf | grep lightdm
kill pid
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a similar behaviour to pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> in Windows, bind that key to the `System Monitor` program, and from there you will be able to get some insights on what process is eating up your performance and kill it.
More on that [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/use-ctrl-alt-del-task-manager-ubuntu/).

By the way, you can click on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and launch `xkill`, more on that [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95192/what-is-the-equivalent-of-control-alt-delete).