# Alt + Ctrl + Del not working

Tags: 16.04, firefox

I've seen [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95192/what-is-the-equivalent-of-control-alt-delete/95202), and it doesn't work. 
(I've tried the following shortcuts: <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>|<kbd>Esc</kbd>|<kbd>F2</kbd>|<kbd>Backspace</kbd>,I've tried <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>U</kbd>,<kbd>B</kbd> under normal conditions and the system didn't respond so I doubt it will when the system freezes )

The freeze is apparently caused by Firefox 58.0.1 even though I didn't installed any extension

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 looking for any shortcut to regain control of the system instead of rebooting every time this occurs (several times a day).

I appreciate your help

**Edit:**
As @Byte Commander have pointed out the shortcut is rather <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>U</kbd>,<kbd>B</kbd> and it causes a hard reboot, then I'd like instead to have control over the system to issue a `kill` command to the process causing the freeze.

Comment: It's not `Alt`+`Ctrl`+`R`,`E`,`I`,`S`,`U`,`B`, but `Alt`+`SysRq`+`R`,`E`,`I`,`S`,`U`,`B` - however, this will do an (almost) hard reboot of your system. It's like holding the power button, just that it orders the kernel to flush all disk caches to prevent corrupt file systems.

Comment: @ByteCommander, thank you for the correction. and yes I would wish to find a better alternative that let me just kill the Firefox process or the one causing the freeze.

Comment: If your graphical session is frozen you can often switch to a TTY, this can be done with Ctrl+Alt+F1 to F6

Comment: Alt+SysRq+K will kill and restart the GUI without hard booting the system.  At least if things are not hung up too badly.  IIRC, Ubuntu started disabling most of the magic sysrq keys by default a few releases ago and you have to fiddle with a sysctl variable to turn them back on.