# Safest way to shut down upon a freeze

Tags: crash

What is the safest way to shut down when the system gets completely frozen? Is there anything we can do outside of pulling the cable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the equivalent of 'Control-Alt-Delete'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95192/what-is-the-equivalent-of-control-alt-delete)

Answer (score 2):

Simply open a new tty using **Ctrl + Alt + F3**, login using your username (name of the home directory) and use **shutdown now** . This should work

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean "completely frozen". Perhaps only the GUI is frozen while the system is still alive? In this case you could launch a tty, by Ctrl + Alt + F2/3/4/5..

When you've logged in into the tty, run `htop` and kill the processes that seem to be troublesome.

Comment: I don't know what it can exactly mean either. Frozen, that is, all audio stops, you cannot move your mouse, et cetera. Ctrl-alt+F I did not try yet.