# How can I *disable* Ctrl+Alt+Backspace?

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xserver, kill

Building on a [question from 2010](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10622/how-can-i-enable-ctrlaltbackspace) (3 years ago) I'm trying to achieve the exact opposite: I want to ***disable*** the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> keyboard shortcut to ***kill the `X server`***. For me, it *appears to be* [disabled](https://askubuntu.com/a/10624/16023) in `System->Preferences->Keyboard` but practically it's still up and running.

<sub>`dontzap` doesn't [seem to be](https://askubuntu.com/a/10624/16023) "active" (as in actively developed) either, and it seems counterintuitive to have to install it in order to disable this key-combo.</sub>

Any other ways to properly disable the shortcut?

---

PS: I think it's a **bug**.

PPS: Some time ago, I enabled it cuz I thought it was *kinda cool* - not knowing that it was a one-way street without a functioning / reliable option to disable it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please edit the file [`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/xorg.conf.5.html):

```
gksu gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

There should be a section in this file called "ServerFlags". If it's not there, add it as below at the end of the file. If it is there, make sure that the line `Option "DontZap" "yes"` is in there with `yes` as a parameter:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
Option "DontZap"  "yes"
EndSection
```

Comment: thx! followed your instructions (the file was *empty* previously). won't test it now, but on a fresh (re-)boot to see if it truly is disabled now...

Comment: ah right. you can also look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there

Comment: `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` was empty. Bad ?

Comment: No, I only shows how old I am. yeah, X detects most of the settings automagically nowadays (and I sit on a 10.04 system which still has a proper xorg.conf).

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: I assume it will have worked; however, now's not the time to risk checking :-) will do so the next time I re-boot, and update this Q&A accordingly.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution worked. At least on my Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 10):

```
echo $'Section "ServerFlags"\n  Option "DontZap" "yes"\nEndSection' | sudo tee /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/dontzap.conf
```

Comment: Thanks - obviously the above answers are ancient as /etc/X11/xorg.conf hasn't been populated for ages now....

Comment: xorg.conf is empty, but I just tried this on Ubuntu 18.04 and it seems to work.