# Preseed values for keyboard-configuration

Tags: 14.04, preseed

I'd like to activate ctrl+alt+backspace on multiple pcs (Ubuntu 14.04) using

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

I don't want to do the dialog every time so i tried:

```
debconf-get-selections | grep "^keyboard-configuration" > config.dat
```

on a host where i answered the dialog with the desired answers

On the host where i want to do it non interactively i tried:

```
debconf-set-selections config.dat

dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive keyboard-configuration
```

it ran without asking, but afterwards the selections where reset to the default values

How can i get dpkg to use my predefined values? Or is there another possibility to enable the ctrl+alt+backspace for all users without going through dialogs?

**EDIT**

to summarize: my problem is that

```
dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive keyboard-configuration
```

doesn't seem to respect my preseeded selections. Can anyone find something wrong in the procedure how i try to do it or could this be a bug?

Comment: Use the gsettings command in this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/367995/158442

Comment: With gsettings i managed to activate it only for gnome. I want it to work everywhere.