# Restart Unity Without Logging Out

Tags: unity, restart

I've used the command

```
unity
```

to restart Unity without logging out, but recently that's been also logging me out. I've also tried using

```
unity --replace
```

but that does the same thing. Can someone either help me get that command working correctly again or tell me another way to restart Unity while still keeping my current session?

If I try

> `sudo service lightdm restart`

my screen goes black, and I just end up restarting my machine entirely.

Comment: I have the same problem. Restarting the X server with [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10622/how-can-i-enable-ctrlaltbackspace) also logs me out. Maybe you could file a bug report.

Comment: That indeed looks like some bug. I've got the same problem.

Comment: @kcpr Have you found a solution? I'm now on Ubuntu 16.04 and I still don't know how to restart Unity without logging out. :/

Comment: @Joschua to be honest I still use Ubuntu 14.04. `compiz --replace` works for me though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is intended behavior. The Display manager (in this case, lightdm) creates and manages the login/x session. When you restart the display manager, you kill the x session and the currently logged in session and must log back in and establish a new session.

Someone more knowledgeable correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and `compiz --replace` seems to work for me.