# CAPS LOCK to CONTROL remap is reset after screen lock

Tags: keyboard, remapping, xkb

I am trying to map my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Control</kbd>. To that end I added the following:

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
```

to the `Startup Applications` menu. This works fine whenever I start the system, however, after unlocking the screen lock the setting is reset back to the default. Why is that? I run Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: It seems like with 15.04 you need a solution that uses `xkbmap` and this is missing from your link.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/347382/354350

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/367995/168219 was helpful eventually.