# How to make control + alt + backspace not automatically restart the X-Window and instead just kill it?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with The Cinnamon desktop environment, and I want to be able to kill the X-Window without it restarting. I already enabled control + alt + backspace in the keyboard settings, but that only restarts the X window, and doesn't terminate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I enable Ctrl+Alt+Backspace?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10622/how-can-i-enable-ctrlaltbackspace)

Comment: I have actually already looked at this, and that's how I figured out how to enable control + alt + backspace. It does not however do what I want. I really would like it to exit X Window all together, and get to a CLI.

Comment: Killing the X server on vt7 will not leave you at a CLI. Those typically are started only on vt1-vt6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this combo does in fact kill the X server, but the init process restarts it. Remember you are running at 'runlevel 5' which typically means a graphical environment. If you just want to work from a terminal you can CTL-ALT-F1 (up to F6). But your X will still be running on the system, albeit maybe swapped out. 
If you want to kill the graphical environment altogether then I think you need to tell Linux to go to "runlevel 3" (multi user with networking traditionally).
The 'telinit 3' command used to be able to do this; not sure if it still does.
You need to be root of course, or use sudo. So you could CTL-ALT-F1 then sudo telinit 3.

With the advent of systemd way of doing things there are no more runlevels, there are now targets. So you need to figure out which target to use, and then get systemd to put you into that target.