# How to kill X server using a key combination?

Tags: shortcut-keys, sudo, xserver, kill

Is there a way to kill the current X server using a keyboard combination?

Is it possible to do so without having `sudo` permissions?

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + Backspace

Comment: That's it? I don't have to set it?

Comment: Sorry! that key combination is to restart X Server

Comment: You have first to set that combination, indeed. Otherwise you can always switch to `tty1` with [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[F1] and then kill it with `killall X`.

Comment: Or just issue it from an x-term. :)

Comment: Yup. Considered some other posts as duplicate. If the OP know about the key combo then it would have been one. As it is I added a link to a similar answer in my post.   I could understand a VTC dup though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In the past the key combination<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>backspace</kbd> was used to kill the X-server.

However:

1. This no longer seems to be the default on many modern installations. You might have to re-enable this by editing a config file.
2. Many modern systems also enable X out of the box and restart it once it terminates. In that case you would kill the x server (and possibly many running programs you started), but a fresh one would start up again.

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10622/how-can-i-enable-ctrlaltbackspace?lq=1) has answers on how to enable the key combination.

Especially the answer "13.10+, type the following on the terminal: 
`dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`" seems relevant.

(That should trigger this screen:)
[image]