# How do you protect Ubuntu login?

Tags: login, lightdm

I seem to remember that a few years back, in order to login on Windows you had to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> to get a login screen.

The advantage of this was that if you had a cat or child that liked to press random keys on your computer keyboard, they wouldn't screw things up.  Well, my kids are in their 40s now, but I do have a cat that likes to walk over the keyboard from time to time, and believe it or not - that requires a reboot to recover from the consequences.

Is there anything (short of hiding the keyboard) that can be done about this?

Comment: Related bug report on Launchpad: [Cat sitting on keyboard crashes lightdm](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1463112) and  especially [Cat causes login screen to hang](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1538615)

Comment: The funny thing is that I find "Press ctrl + alt + delete to login" pretty annoying. Guess it's because I don't have a cat or a child or anything else for that matter that might accidentally "sit" on my keyboard screen.

Comment: Get a wireless keyboard (all of them have a "off" button). "that requires a reboot to recover from the consequences." Nope. control-a and backspace is enough to clear the entry.

Comment: @Parto: That's not the purpose. The purpose of Ctrl+Alt+Del is that it is a Secure Attention Key sequence (SAK), i.e. a key sequence that is handled directly by the kernel, deep down in the guts of the system, and cannot ever be intercepted by a user program, system service or even a kernel driver. So, you *know* when you type the SAK that you are talking to the system itself and not, for example, to a user program that is made to look exactly like the login screen and sends the password you just typed in straight to some Russian crime syndicate (or whatever). Nothing to do with pets or kids.

Comment: The lifehacks SE has solutions [here](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/how-can-i-keep-my-cat-off-my-keyboard) and there are wikihow solutions [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Your-Cat-to-Stop-Jumping-on-Your-Keyboard) that involve teaching you cat to ignore your computer instead of teaching your computer to ignore your cat.

Comment: @JörgWMittag And, the number of people on the planet who would actually "know" that is very small. Most people either think it's an annoyance, unless they have a cat that likes to rest on their keyboard.

Comment: @JörgWMittag [the SAK is mostly history](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83645/does-the-secure-attention-key-really-increase-security) and isn't too relevant nowadays. I still use it on my Windows desktops but more like a keyboard lock/anti-cat mechanism rather than for actual security.

Comment: Although SAK is quite an old concept, if you really want it, you can enable Ctrl-Alt-Backspace to kill the Xserver. A new session will be automatically respawn. I hope. http://askubuntu.com/questions/10622/how-can-i-enable-ctrlaltbackspace

Answer (score 17):

Switch to virtual console *x* (*x* ≥ 8) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F*x*</kbd>, say *x* = 12). Those don't have getty or LightDM (or anything, really) running on them, so the cat can walk over the keyboard to its heart's content. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to LightDM and the login screen.

You could automate this during boot by adding `chvt 12` to `/etc/rc.local` (see [this U&L post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115540/70524)).

Special buttons like the power button might still be a cause for concern.

---

On second thought, other key combinations are available:

- if the virtual console is not running X, then the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F*x*</kbd> can be used without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - just <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F*x*</kbd> would work.

  - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ arrow keys can also be used to switch to the previous and next VTs
  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> triggers a reboot in any of the VTs not running X.

So a better solution might be running an empty X session (not running any other application) in VT12 to cut down the number of available key combinations and switching to it.

```
startx -- :100 vt12 &
chvt12
```

This needs to be tested (you might need to write an `.xinitrc` to override the defaults).

Comment: That's the best solution, taking in account the mentioned bug, etc. But I am afraid that not many people will understand it. There is a small probability that the cat will press Ctrl+Alt+F7 though ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 yes, but you can also lock the screen and then move to a virtual console. It'd be not much different to having to press Ctrl+Alt+Del then having to enter credentials in Windows.

Comment: Won't that write the same enormous amount of data into the prompt?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel what prompt?

Comment: The console prompt, where you type the commands. Or the keyboard input is discarded inside the virtual console?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel for vt8 and above, usually there's nothing running to accept that input. No prompts.

Comment: Basically: a hole deeper than `/dev/null`, where nothing exists?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel the kernel does. It still listens for the keyboard shortcuts for switching VTs, Ctrl-Alt-Del, etc.

Comment: That makes sense. Seems like a good place to leave your computer on, when you leave your feline nearby.

Answer (score 7):

You can to the same by pressing

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

This will lock the screen and require the password to unlock it.

Comment: I guess the OP is already at the login screen and wants something to protect his system from this rather funny but sadly true bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1463112

Comment: It looks like OP is asking how to get to login screen, isn't it?

Comment: And that bug has been fixed recently. It is a duplicate of a fixed bug.

Comment: OP clearly says "in order to login on Windows you had to type Ctrl-Alt-Del to get a login screen" . It's called [secure logon](http://www.super-tnt.com/enable-or-disable-secure-logon-ctrl-alt-delete-in-windows-7.html) So yes, that's for login screen

Comment: A link to the original bug, which has been resolved: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1538615

Comment: @Pilot6: Quite the opposite: the OP is looking for a way to HIDE the login screen when logged out. In windows you had to press Ctrl-Alt-Del to show the login screen otherwise it will just show you the screensaver when pressing any other keys. On most other OSes pressing any key shows the login screen. The OP wants to disable this behaviour and hide the login screen when you press any keys except certain magic key combinations that are not easy to press accidentally.

Answer (score 5):

Some related bug reports on Launchpad:

- [Cat causes login screen to hang](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1538615)
- [Cat sitting on keyboard crashes lightdm](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1463112) (duplicate of first one)

Those bugs describe that `lightdm` (the package behind your login screen) experiences some kind of keyboard input buffer overflow if you keep on hitting keys on the lock or login screen.

The primary bug report mentions that a fix for this bug was finally released for 16.04:
They now limit said input buffer to 200 characters to prevent it from getting filled up with insane amounts of data.

---

So the hanging up if a cat sits on a keyboard on the login screen should be fixed in 16.04 now (maybe you want to upgrade?).

However, I don't think that older releases would profit from a setting that requires you to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> before logging in, as that would then probably be a feature of `lightdm` itself again and would likely not help and suffer from the same bug...

Answer (score 2):

Place pre-warmed cardboard boxes near the keyboard. The cat will default to sitting in these and will leave your computer alone.

Comment: Ah, the social hack is sometimes the most effective.

Answer (score 0):

Excessive keyboard input is known to hang the LightDm screen.

There is currently no way to prevent the problem from happening, however you can easily **remove the characters from the login box** by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> (to select all) then <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (to delete). It may take a few seconds before the machine becomes responsive again.

Note that the issue [has been fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1538615/comments/17) in the next version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I  use Ctrl+A and then type password

Comment: Ctrl+Backspace very often works, too. (Not always on Windows, though.) May or may not work in LightDM.