# Set Ctrl+Alt+Backspace as to kill X server on gnome Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, ubuntu-gnome, 17.10, xserver

There are many question about this topic and all of them has same kind of answer.

1. **With dpkg configuration**:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
   ```
2. **With dconf editor**:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp']"
   ```

source: [How can I enable Ctrl+Alt+Backspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10622/how-can-i-enable-ctrlaltbackspace)

But recently I installed Ubuntu 17.10 and its environment is GNOME. I tried both ways but none of those are working for me.

Can anybody help?

**EDITED:**

There is an another method of `dontzap`. But it is a bug or not available.

Comment: Probably you're in a Wayland session.

Comment: Is Ubuntu 17.10 by default goes in Wayland session?

Comment: Yes, it's default now. You can switch back to Xorg if you wish: https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10