# Change CTRL+ALT+BACKSPACE to restart X server

Tags: xorg, xserver

In search of a way to create another shortcut for restarting X server.

Mainly because I accidentally find myself doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> a lot.

Comment: Well, anything that (reproducibly) cripples or crashes the X Server to the point of requiring a restart should generally be reported as a bug. The developers did not intend X to crash on you! Use the `ubuntu-bug` application to report the issue.

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/10622/how-can-i-enable-ctrlaltbackspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are two steps** to requesting a feature like this.

1. *Has somebody already requested it?*

   Take a look for similar 'Wishlist' bugs in the upstream bug tracker as well as Ubuntu's bug tracker at (launchpad.net). If there is already a bug, read it. If the bug is still open, subscribe to it.
2. *If you are the first, then file the Wishlist bug*

Um...be aware that most upstream developers are often volunteers - they work features that interest them, and they tend to refuse (or ignore) requests for features that do not interest them.

Rather like agreeing to help paint your neighbor's fence - you might agree to do it out of altruism...and you might get bored and drift away from the project after a few minutes.

Of course, if you are skilled and wish to code the feature yourself, that's a different story!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it 18.04. On terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp']"
```

Comment: As it is it does not seem to change the shortcut.