# Change shortcut that restarts X Server (Ctrl-Alt-Backspace)

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, xserver

I occasionally hit this shortcut by accident (for example when using Ctrl-Backspace to remove a word and then switching to another shortcut that involves Alt). This gets me to the login screen and all the programs close.

I haven't found any solutions anywhere on the Internet, searching for hours. Other threads mostly talk about disabling / enabling this shortcut and not about changing it.

Also someone asked this question here, but the accepted answer doesn't answer the question: [Change CTRL+ALT+BACKSPACE to restart X server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005618/change-ctrlaltbackspace-to-restart-x-server)

Currently this shortcut is disabled on my system, but I've read that it should be enabled in case the system hangs.

I want to change the shortcut to something preferably including three different keys, like Ctrl-Alt-Insert for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears not feasible to change that key combination (except perhaps by changing the source code and recompiling the X server). It is indeed [disabled by default](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XorgCtrlAltBackspace) because it is hit quite easily.

You may wish to keep it that way. On the bottom of the linked page, an alternative keyboard combination is indicated that also allows to kill the X server. It is way more difficult to hit by accident:

> For people coming here because they are missing the nice functionality of being able to kill the X server in case nothing else works anymore in the GUI, it might be interesting to know that x can now be killed with "AltGr" - "SysReq" - K (AltGr is the right Alt key. SysReq also labeled "Print, or "Druck" in Germany)!